How to launch minimized to tray apps on startup and how to keep them minimized instead of closing?
I want to have Thunderbird, Telegram and Glate (translator) openend on Ubuntu startup and keep them running in the background instead of closing them

Knowing the version of Ubuntu you are using would probably help to give you some assistance.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Some applications support being launched minimized and display a tray icon (e.g. KeePassX), but most, notably Thunderbird, don't.
Unfortunately, control on how an application launches is not supported at the level of the desktop: it is left to the application to decide on window size, and it can give hints to the window manager where the window should be placed and how (maximized, full screen, ...). When it comes to being displayed in the tray, note that Gnome Shell, the desktop used by standard Ubuntu, does not even implement a tray anymore. Ubuntu added one back through a Gnome Shell extension.
It may be possible to hack something together. Under Xorg, we have the window manipulation tools wmctrl, xprop, xwinfo, xdotool, and once a Gnome Shell extension existed that cobbled this together to automatically minimize a started application. Wayland is fundamentally different. Still, there are extensions that expose dbus interfaces which allow to manipulate windows from the command line and from scripts, e.g. Window calls.
So in brief, you depend on whether the application provides a command line option to start minimized in a tray.

Thank for your reply, I can't figure why Thunderbird lacks of these features...
